# Mozilla displays different css than chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, mozilla

this is css of related code:

```
.hero-section {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;

  h2 {
    // color: rgb(177, 2, 2);
    font-weight: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: GreatVibes;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    color: white;
  }

  perspective: 100rem;
  color: white;
  width: 40rem;
  position: relative;
  &-frontend {
    color: rgb(221, 119, 50);
  }
  &-backend {
    color: rgb(15, 219, 42);
  }
  &-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

this is the result:
[image]
[image]

I changed each property of css to see is any of those properties is causing the issue, I realized that, if change the `height` property, change is reflected on chrome but mozilla.

I used [normalize.css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize.css) and used it in main file but it did not help:

```
 import "normalize.css/normalize.css";
```

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi! I do not remember if I fixed it or not. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that i related to viewport units, VW or VH is not supported as well as in firefox. Try using another kind of units

Comment: I changed it to px, size reflected in mozilla, but it is still different from chrome.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=vh  looks like every modern browser supports vw and vh. Is this an _answer_ or is it a _guess_?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding padding: 0?
Had some similar problems in the past with mozilla and circles and they are usually related to paddings.